# Python: make list iteration faster

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code, but it is very slow. Is there a way to make the code faster?

```
import csv
from statistics import median

with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
    next(reader)
    grades = [float(row[2]) for row in reader]
    for mean_list_value in grades:
        normalization = (mean_list_value / median(grades)) * 500
        print(normalization)
```

test.txt looks like (with approx. 50000 lines):

```
Nr   Name     Grade
2    Max      5.7
5    Linda    6.9
6    Lena     8.0
10   Daniel   4.5
11   Michelle 9.1
.
.
.
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: you can start by not recomputing the `median` every iteration of the loop

Comment: `numpy` would allow a faster solution

Comment: Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for various issues.
https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778

Comment: You should probably say what you are trying to achieve. Sometimes there are bugs in code which may lead ppl to misunderstand what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you're calculating the median 50K times despite being always the same. Since computing the median requires sorting your 50K values, this ends up being pretty intensive.

Below you find a numpy-based snippet.

```py
data = np.loadtxt('text.txt', dtype=str)
grades = [float(g) for g in data[1:, 2]]
norm_grades = grades / np.median(grades) * 500
print(norm_grades)
```